# How do I get rid of milllipedes in the garden?

Tags: vegetables, pest-control, pests, millipedes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with millipedes eating my vegetable seedlings?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/millipedes-eating-my-vegetable-seedlings)

How do I get rid of millipedes they have taken over and are under anything left lying on the ground? I am pretty sure they are responsible for a lot of damage in the garden.

Comment: Hello Mandy, your question has been previously asked on [gardening.se] and has two answers (including one accepted answer). Hence this has been marked as a duplicate. Please read the linked question (see the top of your question under "Possible duplicate") and let us know if that answers your question or not :)